# Below is my code but there is some error when i open camera appear and immediately disappear. How to hold on the camera view for a bit longer.?

Tags: java, android, camera

1.MainActivity.java file
I think the error got at this line

```
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop()
```

I'm trying to open the camera and display using SurfaceView. This delays the loading of the activity for a really long time. So I'm wondering what are the best practices of opening the camera.

```
package com.example.software2.ocrhy;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private String stringResult = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraSource.release();
    }
    private void textRecognizer(){
        textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .build();

        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                SparseArray<TextBlock> sparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i<sparseArray.size(); ++i){
                    TextBlock textBlock = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                    if (textBlock != null && textBlock.getValue() !=null){
                        stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue() + " ");
                    }
                }

                final String stringText = stringBuilder.toString();

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(() -> {
                    stringResult = stringText;
                    resultObtained();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    private void resultObtained(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(stringResult);
        textToSpeech.speak(stringResult, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    }
    public void buttonStart(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.surface);
        textRecognizer();
    }
}
```

[I got full code from this link](https://programmerworld.co/android/how-to-create-your-optical-character-recognition-ocr-android-app-and-convert-the-text-into-speech/)

1. javafile
2. error got in camera activity

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your source code, your camera starts reading the text immediately. If you want to first see your text on your camera and only then start reading it we can break down it to following steps:

1. Open your camera
2. Navigate to specific text
3. Finally when you see via your camera the text what you want to read it

I suggest you to do small modifications on your code

1. Add `Capture` button on your surfaceview.xml (for example in a code below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <SurfaceView
       android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
       android:layout_width="308dp"
       android:layout_height="503dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       android:id="@+id/capture"
       android:layout_marginHorizontal="32dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
       android:text="Capture"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. Move out text processing to separate function

```
private void capture() {
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                SparseArray<TextBlock> sparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i<sparseArray.size(); ++i){
                    TextBlock textBlock = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                    if (textBlock != null && textBlock.getValue() !=null){
                        stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue() + " ");
                    }
                }

                final String stringText = stringBuilder.toString();

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                   stringResult = stringText;
                   resultObtained();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

3. Capture your text on `capture` button click

```
public void buttonStart(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.surfaceview);
        Button capture = findViewById(R.id.capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(v -> capture());
        textRecognizer();
}
```

As a result whole MainActivity

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;

    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;

    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private String stringResult = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraSource.release();
    }

    private void textRecognizer() {
        textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        Context context = this;
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
    }
    private void capture() {
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                SparseArray<TextBlock> sparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i<sparseArray.size(); ++i){
                    TextBlock textBlock = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                    if (textBlock != null && textBlock.getValue() !=null){
                        stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue() + " ");
                    }
                }

                final String stringText = stringBuilder.toString();

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stringResult = stringText;
                        resultObtained();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void resultObtained(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(stringResult);
        textToSpeech.speak(stringResult, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    }

    public void buttonStart(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.surfaceview);
        Button capture = findViewById(R.id.capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(v -> capture());
        textRecognizer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide me full MainActivity.java Code

Comment: @AkshayWaghmare Now you may look at final MainActivity. Don't forget to past your own package on the top of the MainActivity.

Comment: @AkshayWaghmare when you copy & past MainActivity Android Studio must indicate your package, just make sure it is right package. It might be not critical though.

Comment: Please sir can you provide full source code Sincerely request I got error at capture button

Comment: MainActivity is complete code. What error do you face?

Comment: @AkshayWaghmare did you copy & pasted `surfaceview.xml` on the first step above?

Comment: Sir now my application is working fine but when i open camera not clear text is visible as well as it does not allow to zoom that text

Comment: What error is that?

Comment: Yeap, but it allows to capture text and speak it right?

Comment: If you want to add zoom and other features it will be other question here.

Comment: Yes it detect the text... but some it is not clear only larger letters are capture that the problem.

Comment: And it resolved your question here, it does not crush on camera anymore.

Comment: So you need to move the next step, either it is camera zoom or clearness.

Comment: Yes the only problem remaining is clearness

Comment: It means my answer is correct! Your camera does not crush and you can hold on your camera as much as you want.

Comment: Yes i can hold on camera as much as I want. But can you give me some kind of hint why my camera is not clear? but my system camera has high mega pixel .

Comment: Another update is above. 
I added `.setAutoFocusEnabled(true)` to `CameraSource` builder. Your camera will try to focus automatically not.

Comment: Really thank you sir . I completed my application successfully.

Comment: You are welcome! Now this is the time to mark my answer as correct answer.

Comment: this is not an error but when i debug the app it says ---> E/CameraSource: Exception thrown from receiver.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detector processor must first be set with setProcessor in order to receive detection results.